# How to make a DM prompt in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've just learned how to send a DM from a Discord.js bot, but how can I turn it into a prompt? My code looks like this at the moment:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content == "hello") {
      message.author.send("Hello!");
    }
  }
});
```

But how can I store data about what's happening in that dm? If I was making a bot like Application Bot, it would choose what to reply with based on previous dms, how can I make that work? Would I have to use a database? Thanks!

Comment: Wdym with prompt? Also yeah, for an ongoing series involving several commands/replies, a database is usually the way to go

Comment: So... you're making an AI? If you want them to reply using a list of preset answers, then you can use a static database on it and use the `for()` loop. You can send all the data of what people say and send it to you, then you can manually add it to the static database and the next time they say it, it will reply using the preset answer. But, if you want it to _automatically_ reply, then...

Comment: By a prompt, I mean like if I wanted to make a command to apply for a job, it asks you what job, then it asks other questions based of what you answered on the 1st question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a message collector, either with [`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) or [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector).

With `awaitMessages`:

```js
// Discord.js v12
const messagesPromise = message.dmChannel.awaitMessages(
  // This is a filter function that allows you to only receive certain messages.
  // Return true to receive the message.
  // This filter will accept all messages.
  msg => true,
  // Options. This example makes the promise resolve after 1 message has been
  // collected.
  {max: 1}
);

// Discord.js v13
const messagesPromise = message.dmChannel.awaitMessages(
  // This example makes the promise resolve after 1 message has been
  // collected.
  {max: 1}
);

messagesPromise.then(messages => {
  // messages is a Collection of messages
  const msg = messages.first();
  // do something...
});
```

With `createMessageCollector`:

```js
// Discord.js v12
const collector = message.dmChannel.createMessageCollector(msg => true, {max: 1})

// Discord.js v13
const collector = message.dmChannel.createMessageCollector({max: 1})

collector.on("collect", msg => {
  // do something...
});
```

You can also use ES2017's `async`/`await` syntax with `awaitMessages`:

```js
// Note the async here
//                   vvvvv
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content == "hello") {
      message.author.send("Hello!");

      const messages = await message.dmChannel.awaitMessages(
        /* () => true, for Discord.js v12 */
        {max: 1}
      );
      const msg = messages.first();
      // do something...
    }
  }
});
```

For more information see [‘Collectors’ on the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors).